# Samsung stuck at boot options screen

Tags: windows, boot-manager

I have a np300e5c that's stuck at the boot options screen. It shows two identical Windows boot manager options, I can't get passed this, every time I select one, it just comes back to the same screen. Any thoughts as to the cause?

Comment: Can you add system specs, what you did before this, any modifications you may have made.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from your windows setup DVD and right before it says 'install now' click 'repair your computer'. Then you'll find options to restore your startup process, and that might help you to boot again.

If that doesn't work you can try to boot into safemode to identify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I had the same problem and i disabled secure boot and it seems to have solved the issue.

You can access *Secure boot* from the *boot* tab in the *setup* screen.